# Get Ranorex to use same user code for all tests

Tags: ranorex

Is it possible to configure Ranorex to use the same user code to identify buttons in an application (instead of renaming them for each test) and also to have a set of user defined code for any new tests. I.e. a common user code base for all tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and very handy. What you do is have a code module library that inherits from `ITestModule`, e.g.

> public class GenericActionsLibrary : ITestModule

and then in the user code section of the recording module have the class inherit from your library.

> public class TestLoginScreen : GenericActionsLibrary

In the recording module, each time you add a user code action, the drop-down list is filled with methods from both the user code module and the `GenericActionsLibrary`.

Your `GenericActionsLibrary` will need its own static reference to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. I'm using Visual Basic (VB) and not C# CS in Ranorex.

In Ranorex

- "Add Code Module" `MainLibrary`
- "Add Code Module" `StartBrowser`

Comment out three code blocks in the code module `MainLibrary`:

The first is

```
'Implements ITestModule
```

The second is

```
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Constructs a new instance.
        ''' </summary>
'        Public Sub New()
'            ' Do not delete - a parameterless constructor is required!
'        End Sub
```

The third location is

```
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Performs the playback of actions in this module.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks>You should not call this method directly, instead pass the module
        ''' instance to the <see cref="TestModuleRunner.Run(Of ITestModule)"/> method
        ''' that will in turn invoke this method.</remarks>
'        Sub Run() Implements ITestModule.Run
'            Mouse.DefaultMoveTime = 300
'            Keyboard.DefaultKeyPressTime = 100
'            Delay.SpeedFactor = 1.0
'        End Sub
```

Add `Sub`(s) for the action(s) you want to call from the other code module(s)

```
Public Sub OpenBrowser
    Host.Local.OpenBrowser("http://www.ranorex.com", "IE", "", False, False)
End Sub
```

In the code module, you are calling the method that's in `MainLibrary`. Add the `Inherits` statement before the `Implements` statement, then call the method from the `MainLibrary` in the `ITestModule.Run` code block:

```
   Public Class StartBrowser
        Inherits MainLibrary
        Implements ITestModule

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Constructs a new instance.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub New()
            ' Do not delete - a parameterless constructor is required!
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Performs the playback of actions in this module.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks>You should not call this method directly, instead pass the module
        ''' instance to the <see cref="TestModuleRunner.Run(Of ITestModule)"/> method
        ''' that will in turn invoke this method.</remarks>
        Sub StartBrowser_Run() Implements ITestModule.Run
            Mouse.DefaultMoveTime = 300
            Keyboard.DefaultKeyPressTime = 100
            Delay.SpeedFactor = 1.0

            'Call the public method from MainLibrary Class.
            OpenBrowser()
        End Sub

    End Class
```

On [Ranorex's Website](http://www.ranorex.com/blog/organizing-a-test-automation-project-with-ranorex-studio), it shows about creating library's that comes in handy when reusing for different projects.